# Regex validation on bracketed [] string

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use regex to validate one of the textfield which only a certain format is allow

Sample: [Apple][Orange][Durian]ABC

Here are some rules of the format

1. No characters allowed in between bracketed items and at the start of the string.
2. At least one bracketed item but not more then 5.
3. Only these string words are allowed in bracketed items: Apple, Orange, Durian, Pear.
4. Entire string not more then 100 characters.

I came out with this: `"(<?bracket>\[(Apple|Orange|Durian )\]){1,5}"` but I got this error when trying to load my page:

parsing ""(?bracket" - Not enough )'s. 
Can anyone assist with the regex according to the format rules, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is the string `<?bracket>` doing there? I don't think that's part of any regexp syntax, and I'm not finding it as an asp.net-specific thing either.

Regarding your four criteria:

1) Put a caret (the character ^) at the beginning of the regular expression. This indicates that whatever comes after it has to be the beginning of the field.

2) I think you have this one right. Enclose the entire expression in parentheses, followed by `{1,5}`

3) I think this is right. Do the words need to be capitalized? If not, remember to either specify lowercase letters as an alternative (e.g. `[Dd]urian`) or add a case-insensitive modifier to the entire expression.

4) I don't think you can do this using the same regular expression. You would need to do a separate validation step to see if the string matches something like `^.{1,100}$` .

Comment: Removing the <?bracket> works, now the only restriction that is not working is that I can't add anymore characters after the last bracketed string.

Comment: In that case it sounds like it's testing for a complete match between the regular expression and the field content, rather than a partial match. You should be able to change that behavior but I don't know how, offhand. As a workaround you could just add `.+` to the end of the regexp, to indicate that any additional characters are valid. 

The second validation step, which I mentioned for criterion 4, should still make sure that the entire string is within the length limit.